# AspectJ (ajc) with Modules

Tags: java, aspectj, java-module, ecj, ajc

I am using AspectJ 1.9.7 and I am trying to compile a modular application with `ajc`. Let's suppose I have a single module called `test` and the following tree:

```
.
└── test
    ├── aspectj
    │   ├── Main.java
    │   └── TestAspect.aj
    └── module-info.java
```

With `javac` the command I would use to compile it is:

```
javac --module-source-path . -d ../bin -m test
```

And everything works fine, of course without the weaving process. Instead, if I try to run the same line with `ajc` (`ajc --module-source-path . -d ../bin -m test`), the output is:

```
[error] build config error: dir arg not permitted: test
    
[error] unrecognized single argument: "-m"
    
[error] no sources specified
    

3 errors
```

I guess at this point that the `-m` option is not supported. I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316904/confused-how-ajc-works-with-javac), where a user says that it is possible to specify the option `-usejavac` to *use javac* in the compilation process but, at least for me, does not work and the option is not even recognized.

#### 1) How to use `--module-source-path` with `ajc`?

---

Assuming `--module-source-path` is not supported, I have opted for the `--module-path` option. Again, with `javac`, everything ok:

```
javac -d bin --module-path test $(find . -name *.java)
```

But switching to `ajc` (`ajc -d bin --module-path test $(find . -name *.java -o -name *.aj)`), the output is this:

```
/home/maluz/Desktop/OneDrive/First Semester/TSP/labs/lab2/Test/test/module-info.java:1 [error] Syntax error on token "module", aspect expected
module test {
^^^^^

1 error
```

Same output when I remove `--module-path`.

#### 2) Is there a way to compile a module with `ajc`?

The alternative would be something like:

```
# I compile every *.java and *.aj except module-info.java with ajc
$ ajc -d bin $(find . \( -name *.java -o -name *.aj \) -and \( -not -name *module-info.java \))

# I compile module-info.java separately with javac
$ javac --module-path test -d bin/ test/module-info.java
```

It works but there must be a way to do it with `ajc`, given that `--module-path` and `--module-source-path` are documented under the *Module compilation options* of `ajc` man. I am not sure this is relevant, but I am using `openjdk 15.0.2 2021-01-19`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this blog](http://andrewclement.blogspot.com/), I found a partial solution. The first question is still unanswered because the `--module` option is unrecognized. Nonetheless, it seems possible to compile a module with `ajc`:

```
ajc -d bin --release 15 --module-path path/to/aspectjrt.jar $$(find . -name *.java -o -name *.aj)
```

And a small change in the `module-info.java`:

```
module test {
    exports aspectj;
    requires org.aspectj.runtime;
}
```

As for what I have understood, you need to specify the java version your application is compatible with: this is done with `--release` option.

Then, in order to use AspectJ classes and runtime types, you need to import the `aspectjrt.jar` into the module path and `require` the automatic module name in the `module-info.java`. This jar is placed by default in `$HOME/aspectj${version}/lib/aspectjrt.jar`.

---

I am not accepting my answer because the `--module-source-path` with `ajc` is still a mistery to me.

Comment: Thanks for raising this question. Currently we have a [bug when parsing the `--module-source-path` option](https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/issues/118) in AJC (which is derived from ECJ, the Eclipse Java Compiler), causing the compiler to core-dump. This can probably be fixed, but please note that even so, ECJ currently has a [problem handling module source paths with `*`](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=578306), i.e. if you want to use multi-module compilation mode, you need to use the default directory layout with modules directly below the specified base directory.

Comment: May I ask why you want to use multi-module compilation mode? In your described case, I see no benefit. If you are expecting `--module-source-path` to enable you to not having to specify all the files to be compiled anymore, I have to disappoint you. This is neither the case with Javac nor with ECJ. You still have to list all source files.

Comment: @kriegaex Thank you for explaining the current situation. I am just exploring AspectJ and  wanted to test if it entirely supports module. *This is neither the case with Javac nor with ECJ*, with javac something like this `javac --module-source-path . -d output-folder -m mod1(,mod)*` should work as far as I know. Why do you say the opposite?

Comment: Maybe because I am a total JMS noob and never used modules in any of my projects before. I had no idea that I have to combine those two CLI options. I am going to check later when I am near a computer again, being on the road just now. Sorry if I might have said something stupid. You definitely know more about modules than I do.

Comment: Actually, I have learned that recently, we are probably not on different levels (I am a noob too). I read the book *The Java Module System by Nicolai Parlog* and from the paragraph 4.3.4 he explains pros and cons of `--module-source-path` combined with `--module`.

Comment: That works nicely with Javac, but there is no `--module <module>(,<module>)*` or `-m <module>(,<module>)*` option in ECJ. Therefore, it also does not exist in ACJ. I.e., presently you need to compile each module separately and really specify all source files literally, with `$(find ...)` or with a source list file.

Comment: Thank you again for looking into this.